# Como passar parâmetros de um Fragment para outro Fragment no mesmo FrameLayout?

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma Activity principal que tem UM frameLayout. O frameLayout inicia com o FragmentA.
FragmentA tem um botão que chama FragmentB abrindo no mesmo frameLayout, substituindo o FragmentA.
Como passar parâmetros do FragmentA para o FragmentB no mesmo framelayout e assim sucessivamente, caso tenha FragmentC, passando A para o B e B para o C?

Código

### MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.frameInicial, new FragmentA(), "NewFragmentTag");
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

### FragmentA:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment  {

    public FragmentA() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

        Button btChamaFragmentB = view.findViewById(R.id.btChamaFragmentB);

        btChamaFragmentB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.frameInicial, new FragmentB(), "NewFragmentTag");
                ft.commit();

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

### FragmentB

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    public FragmentB() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

### XML - Layout da MainActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="aig.example.com.comunicacaofragment.MainActivity">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameInicial"
        android:name="aig.example.com.menudeslizante.Fragment1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

conseguir resolver o problema e irei compartilhar com vocês.

Para chamar outra fragment passando parâmetro utilize o código abaixo:

`FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                bundle.putString("ano", "2018");
                fragmentB.setArguments(bundle);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameInicial, fragmentB ,"NewFragmentTag");
                fragmentTransaction.commit();`

Para receber o parâmetro na nova fragment utilize o código abaixo:

```
   ` Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
    if(mBundle != null){
        mBundle = getArguments();
        ano = mBundle.getString("ano");`

    }
```